# Did we ever learn more about Gary Seven's homeworld?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-eu

In the TOS episode "Assignment: Earth", the Enterprise travels back in time to the 20th century.  While there they intercept a transporter beam beyond even their technology, and the traveler, Gary 7, explains that he comes from a planet hidden even in the 23rd century.

Was there ever any more information given about Gary's homeworld in future Star Trek shows, or in extended material?  Given their concern for humanity (and presumably other local cultures) I'm curious why they didn't reveal themselves to some extent and take more direct action in certain pivitol crisis (like the Dominion war).

Comment: There's a huge amount of additional info in the EU novels about Gary Seven. Too much to easily summarise; http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Gary_Seven

Comment: *Assignment: Earth* was originally intended as the pilot to a proposed spin-off featuring Gary 7, basically a sci-fi version of Roger Moore's *The Saint*. When the episode did poorly, the idea was dropped. While a lot of information about Gary 7 has been released in the form of novels, as @Richard states, some of it is contradictory and none of it ever appeared onscreen, making it non-canon.

Comment: There are a couple of examples of fan fiction opening credits to what the show might have looked like. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6lmBbV3VWo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmynXHrR74w

Comment: While, as everyone knows that there very much info about Gary Seven, I remember that when he materializes in the Enterprise transporter room, he takes one look at Spock and says, "You're a Vulcainian". This makes the crew very suspicious because no human being in the 20th century should know that Vulcans exist, let alone know what they look like.

Comment: If you want to get pedantic, Gary Seven's homeworld is Earth. His ancestors were abducted from Earth about 4000BC and raised and trained on the world in discussion to serve as agents and supervisors for missions back on Earth.

Comment: I still don't understand what happened to Garys 1 through 6. Was it something to do with the Vorlons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Within the main canon of Star Trek films, TV series and the animated series there are **no further mentions** of the planet from which Gary Seven emanated (referred to on Memory Alpha as [the ***Planet of the Assigners***](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Gary_Seven%27s_homeworld)). The episode in which he appeared was intended to be a [backdoor pilot](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PoorlyDisguisedPilot?from=Main.BackdoorPilot) for a spin-off show that ultimately never happened for a [variety of reasons](https://www.assignmentearth.ca/files/assignmentearth-adamriggio.pdf) and further mentions seem to be have been intentionally avoided.

Note that he states that his "homeworld" is not a human world but is, in fact a cloaked alien world and that he was simply one of a potentially wide variety of species that had been abducted in their cultural infancy and used as forced breeding stock for future generations of covert agents :

> **SEVEN:** *Roberta, you've got to believe me. Look, a truly advanced planet wouldn't use force. They wouldn't come here in strange alien forms. The best of all possible methods would be to take human beings to their world, train them for generations until they're needed here.*

---

As far as "[Extended materials](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Gary_Seven)" are concerned, Gary Seven appears over a dozen licensed books and comics as well as numerous fanfic stories.

Although his homeworld remains shrouded in mystery in all of these properties, we can find a short excerpt in [The Rise and Fall of Khan Noonien Singh, Vol 1](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Rise_and_Fall_of_Khan_Noonien_Singh,_Volume_1) where Gary almost blabs the location of this cloaked planet:

> “Where do you come from?” she cross-examined Seven. “Where?”
>
> She held her breath as the crucial information dribbled out of Seven with excruciating slowness, one word at a time. “Cloaked planet, light-yearss away, located in Ssystem Zeta-Gamma-Five-Three-Ssev-“

Answer (score -2):

Good Lord am I the only person who remembers the Enterprise D visited that world? They put out a destress call and when the Enterprise arrived at the coordinates there was no planet. Then they decloaked. The people had a declining birthrate and in danger of going extinct. The Enterprise crew determined the cloaking technology had a slow cumulative effect and had to be shut down to fix the problem. Seriously no one but me remembers that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  A reference to the specific episode would be nice, but how are you sure it's the same world?

Comment: @Benton Marcum - Sounds like you're referring to the planet [Aldea](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Aldea), from the episode "[When The Bough Breaks](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/When_The_Bough_Breaks_(episode))." And if that is the episode you're thinking of, you're certainly not the only one who remembers it. However, there's no indication I'm aware of that that planet has anything to do with Gary Seven. Do you know of evidence that it does, or did you just assume that?

Comment: The first two seasons drew heavily from STOS, repeatedly referencing canon from those episodes. Example: The self replicating molecule created from exposure of water to fluctuating gravity fields. It was established in Assignment Earth the planet was cloaked when they backtracked the transporter beam. Incredibly advanced tech, able to push  Enterprise hundreds of LY's in the blink of an eye, planetary cloak. Why would you assume that wasn't Gary's planet?

Comment: @Benton Marcum - I don't advocate assuming that it is or isn't the same planet. That said, the writers didn't include any clear reference to "Assignment: Earth" within "When The Bough Breaks," which seems odd if they intended it to be the same planet.

Comment: I'm a great advocate of assuming. Because when I assume something I make an @$$ out of U and Me. Since you are clearly unfamiliar with the laws of the universe allow me to educate you. The five basic laws of the universe are. (1) Ben is never wrong.    (2) When Ben is wrong refer to law (1).       (3) Ben is never wrong ignore law (2).      (4) If you disagree with Ben you're wrong.     (5) If you agree with Ben you're still wrong